# Map identical dictionary keys to different values in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
    myDict = {'lion,zebra': 'mammal',
              'hawk': 'bird',
              'snake': 'reptile',
              'zebra': 'herbivore'}
```

I'd like to obtain the following mapping as a dictionary with a unique key and associated list of values:

```
output = {'lion': ['mammal'],
          'zebra': ['mammal', 'herbivore'],
          'hawk': ['bird'],
          'snake': ['reptile']}
```

I did try to split the dictionary keys as a function of the contained comma, but it didn't go too far. I appreciate this might be a basic question, and it was probably asked before, but I couldn't find any answer I can use.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: show your code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `setdefault` and a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
myDict = {'lion,zebra': 'mammal',
          'hawk': 'bird',
          'snake': 'reptile',
          'zebra': 'herbivore'}

result = {}
for k, v in myDict.items():
    for ani in k.split(","):
        result.setdefault(ani, []).append(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'hawk': ['bird'],
 'lion': ['mammal'],
 'snake': ['reptile'],
 'zebra': ['mammal', 'herbivore']}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `collections.defaultdict` object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = {'lion,zebra': 'mammal', 'hawk': 'bird',
          'snake': 'reptile', 'zebra': 'herbivore'}
d = defaultdict(list)
for keys, v in myDict.items():
    for k in keys.split(','):
        d[k].append(v)
print(dict(d))
```

The output:

```
{'lion': ['mammal'], 'zebra': ['mammal', 'herbivore'], 'hawk': ['bird'], 'snake': ['reptile']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if key exists in dict:

```
myDict = {
    'lion,zebra': 'mammal',
    'hawk': 'bird',
    'snake': 'reptile',
    'zebra': 'herbivore'
}

output = {}
for keys, value in myDict.items():
    for key in keys.split(','):
        if key in output:
            output[key].append(value)
        else:
            output[key] = [value]
```